# recuperar el valor 'titulo' de un boton

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, swift3

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let identifier = "item"

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        //print("Posicion" , indexPath)
        cell.btnCollection.setTitle(String(describing: indexPath), for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.btnCollection.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
```

Estoy creando un boton y le asigno un valor como titulo de esta forma

```
cell.btnCollection.setTitle(String(describing: indexPath), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

y al mismo tiempo le asigno una accion clic a cada boton

```
cell.btnCollection.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

y la funcion que se ejecuta al hacer clic en los botones es el siguiente

```
 @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        //var Alert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert",message: "dsdsd" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        //self.present(Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
```

Me gustaria saber como puedo recuperar el valor "titulo" del boton que presiono y mostrarlo en el Alert

Comment: al igual que tienes `setTitle` deberías tener `getTitle` o `getProperty`. Mira la documentacion del boton, intenta implementarlo y si no te sale muestra el intento y los errores o problemas. Un saludo

Comment: No tengo esa opcion dentro de las propiedades del boton

Comment: No conozco [tag:swift] pero tras una unica busqueda en google ( *"swift button get title"*) he encontrado la solucion a tu pregunta. Mira el elemento `sender` a ver si puedes extraer el titulo de ahí. Un saludo

Comment: Excelente, sin duda en un post de ingles encontre la solucion aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array . 
y la funcion no es getTitle es CurrentTitle

Comment: A lo que queria llegar con esto, es que es **muy importante** buscar e intentarlo primero, y si los problemas persisten entonces preguntar. Me alegro que te funcione. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener el título del botón con el método `title(for:)`.

[Aquí puedes ver la documentación](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624022-title) (en inglés), dice:

> Returns the title associated with the specified state.

es decir:

> Devuelve el título asociado con el estado especificado.

En tu código:

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    if let title = sender.title(for: .normal) {
        // hacer algo con "title"
    }
    ...
}
```

Otra opción es usar un [`tag`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag) para cada botón, y preguntar por el `tag` en vez de por el título.